Error: Python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully. While installing intel-extension-for-transformers
I am following the tutorial https://intel.github.io/intel-extension-for-pytorch/llm/llama3/xpu/ to run Llama 3 models locally, however I am getting the following error while setting up the environment and running the command pip install -v . .
 Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\rohit\intel-extension-for-transformers\setup.py", line 14, in <module>
      from intel_extension_for_transformers.tools.utils import get_gpu_family
    File "C:\Users\rohit\intel-extension-for-transformers\intel_extension_for_transformers\tools\utils.py", line 21, in <module>
      import torch
    File "C:\Users\rohit\miniconda3\envs\llm\lib\site-packages\torch\__init__.py", line 139, in <module>
      raise err
  OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\rohit\miniconda3\envs\llm\lib\site-packages\torch\lib\backend_with_compiler.dll" or one of its dependencies.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  full command: 'C:\Users\rohit\miniconda3\envs\llm\python.exe' -c '
  exec(compile('"'"''"'"''"'"'
  # This is <pip-setuptools-caller> -- a caller that pip uses to run setup.py
  #
  # - It imports setuptools before invoking setup.py, to enable projects that directly
  #   import from `distutils.core` to work with newer packaging standards.
  # - It provides a clear error message when setuptools is not installed.
  # - It sets `sys.argv[0]` to the underlying `setup.py`, when invoking `setup.py` so
  #   setuptools doesn'"'"'t think the script is `-c`. This avoids the following warning:
  #     manifest_maker: standard file '"'"'-c'"'"' not found".
  # - It generates a shim setup.py, for handling setup.cfg-only projects.
  import os, sys, tokenize

  try:
      import setuptools
  except ImportError as error:
      print(
          "ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in "
          "the build environment.",
          file=sys.stderr,
      )
      sys.exit(1)

  __file__ = %r
  sys.argv[0] = __file__

  if os.path.exists(__file__):
      filename = __file__
      with tokenize.open(__file__) as f:
          setup_py_code = f.read()
  else:
      filename = "<auto-generated setuptools caller>"
      setup_py_code = "from setuptools import setup; setup()"

  exec(compile(setup_py_code, filename, "exec"))
  '"'"''"'"''"'"' % ('"'"'C:\\Users\\rohit\\intel-extension-for-transformers\\setup.py'"'"',), "<pip-setuptools-caller>", "exec"))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\rohit\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-upvjd4iu'
  cwd: C:\Users\rohit\intel-extension-for-transformers\
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I'm not sure if its an error with pip as I ran pip install --upgrade setuptools, which was a popular solution upon researching this issue, with no avail. I even tried regressed the python version to 3.6 and tried running the command but it did not work. Please look into this issue.
